# Python for loops in Square Brackets what is this type of for loop called?

Tags: python

I have used this method to create threads after seeing a good sight for making threads - but I had no idea a for loop could be used like this!

What is this approached called and what other ways can I used this approach?

```
    # create threads
    threads = [Thread(target=replace, args=(filename, 'id', 'ids')) for filename in filenames]
```

Comment: That is a list comprehension, read the answers in the linked duplicate for more information

Answer (score 0):

This is known as [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension), and is very powerful. It can be used in a multitude of situations and can even be used for things like dictionaries.

More random articles and examples of list comprehension's many uses:

- https://www.educba.com/python-list-comprehension/
- https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python
- https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp